# Defaulting the DataKeyNames on a RADGrid to the first column

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, telerik-grid

I have a Telerik RadGrid on my page which is used to display loads of different result sets (one at a time) based on various queries.

I need to default the `DataKeyNames` property to the first column regardless of what dataset is returned.

The problem I have is the the name of the first column changes from dataset to dataset.

Is there a way to default the property to the first column regardless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it myself.  Essentially just building the grid manually for each separate report, pain but it's done now.